# How do I read a date in Excel format in Python?

Tags: python, excel, datetime

How can I convert an Excel date (in a number format) to a proper date in Python?

Comment: Please clarify: give an example of "Excel data (in a number format)"

Comment: Internally, Excel stores dates as floating numbers, and you can distinguish from "normal" numbers only by the format of the cell.

Comment: @Roberto Liffredo, yes I know that Excel stored dates as floating numbers, I need to convert them to a proper date and that is why I am asking this question.
@eliben, please see Roberto's comment

Comment: You might also want to check the answer in [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962837/reading-date-as-a-string-not-float-from-excel-using-python-xlrd).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).

From its [documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), you can read that dates are always stored as numbers; however, you can use [`xldate_as_tuple`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_tuple) to convert it to a python date.

Note: the version on the PyPI seems more up-to-date than the one available on xlrd's website.

Answer (score 30):

Here's the bare-knuckle no-seat-belts use-at-own-risk version:

```
import datetime

def minimalist_xldate_as_datetime(xldate, datemode):
    # datemode: 0 for 1900-based, 1 for 1904-based
    return (
        datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
        + datetime.timedelta(days=xldate + 1462 * datemode)
        )
```

Comment: For 1900-based Excel dates this will give incorrect `datetime`s for Excel dates before 1 Mar 1900. This is due to a bug in Excel that makes it (incorrectly) think that 1900 was a leap year. See [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326)

Comment: And furthermore for the very un-computer-science-like assumption that for some reason the start of the year in 1900 falls on a 1. As if it is the Middle Ages and we didn't understand the concept of 0; cheers Microsoft.

Comment: @AER Not really microsoft's fault, they inherited this insanity when they implemented Lotus 123's datetime.  Also, plenty of languages index from 1, most of the science languages index from 1

Answer (score 28):

After testing and a few days wait for feedback, I'll svn-commit the following whole new function in xlrd's xldate module ... note that it won't be available to the diehards still running Python 2.1 or 2.2.

```
##
# Convert an Excel number (presumed to represent a date, a datetime or a time) into
# a Python datetime.datetime
# @param xldate The Excel number
# @param datemode 0: 1900-based, 1: 1904-based.
# <br>WARNING: when using this function to
# interpret the contents of a workbook, you should pass in the Book.datemode
# attribute of that workbook. Whether
# the workbook has ever been anywhere near a Macintosh is irrelevant.
# @return a datetime.datetime object, to the nearest_second.
# <br>Special case: if 0.0 <= xldate < 1.0, it is assumed to represent a time;
# a datetime.time object will be returned.
# <br>Note: 1904-01-01 is not regarded as a valid date in the datemode 1 system; its "serial number"
# is zero.
# @throws XLDateNegative xldate < 0.00
# @throws XLDateAmbiguous The 1900 leap-year problem (datemode == 0 and 1.0 <= xldate < 61.0)
# @throws XLDateTooLarge Gregorian year 10000 or later
# @throws XLDateBadDatemode datemode arg is neither 0 nor 1
# @throws XLDateError Covers the 4 specific errors

def xldate_as_datetime(xldate, datemode):
    if datemode not in (0, 1):
        raise XLDateBadDatemode(datemode)
    if xldate == 0.00:
        return datetime.time(0, 0, 0)
    if xldate < 0.00:
        raise XLDateNegative(xldate)
    xldays = int(xldate)
    frac = xldate - xldays
    seconds = int(round(frac * 86400.0))
    assert 0 <= seconds <= 86400
    if seconds == 86400:
        seconds = 0
        xldays += 1
    if xldays >= _XLDAYS_TOO_LARGE[datemode]:
        raise XLDateTooLarge(xldate)

    if xldays == 0:
        # second = seconds % 60; minutes = seconds // 60
        minutes, second = divmod(seconds, 60)
        # minute = minutes % 60; hour    = minutes // 60
        hour, minute = divmod(minutes, 60)
        return datetime.time(hour, minute, second)

    if xldays < 61 and datemode == 0:
        raise XLDateAmbiguous(xldate)

    return (
        datetime.datetime.fromordinal(xldays + 693594 + 1462 * datemode)
        + datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
        )
```

Comment: Hi @JohnMachin sorry to revive an old thread but did you commit this. I'm on Ubuntu and python 2.7 and it isn't present in the version I'm using.

Comment: The `xldate_as_datetime` function was added to the `xldate` module as of xlrd version 0.9.3 (released to PyPI in April 2014).

Comment: `xldate_as_datetime` is a much cleaner option than `xldate_as_tuple` in my opinion

Answer (score 24):

`xlrd.xldate_as_tuple` is nice, but there's `xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime` that converts to datetime as well.

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(41889, wb.datemode)
=> datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 7, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 10):

Please refer to this link: [Reading date as a string not float from excel using python xlrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962837/reading-date-as-a-string-not-float-from-excel-using-python-xlrd)

it worked for me:

in shot this the link has:

```
import datetime, xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
a1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode))
print 'datetime: %s' % a1_as_datetime
```

Comment: i hope i have not done something wrong here, i just want to give direction to right answer here.

Comment: No worries! It would probably have been more adequate to put a link to the duplicate question as a comment on this question, but putting it as an answer is, at least for me, fine as well.

Comment: sure from next time will only put the link and not copying the answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: Great example, i just added `strftime` for my formatting `a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 6):

Expected situation

```
# Wrong output from cell_values()
42884.0

# Expected output
2017-5-29
```

Example: Let **cell_values(2,2)** from sheet number **0** will be the date
targeted

Get the required variables as the following

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("target.xlsx")
 
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

wrongValue = sheet.cell_value(2,2)
```

And make use of **xldate_as_tuple**

```
year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(wrongValue, workbook.datemode)
print("{0} - {1} - {2}".format(year, month, day))
```

That's my solution

Answer (score 5):

Incase you're using pandas and your read_excel reads in Date formatted as Excel numbers improperly and need to recover the real dates behind...

The `lambda function` applied on the column uses xlrd to recover the date back

```
import xlrd
df['possible_intdate'] = df['possible_intdate'].apply(lambda s: xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(s, 0))


>> df['possible_intdate']

   dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there's a chance that your excel files are coming from different computers/people; there's a chance that the formatting is messy; so be extra cautious.

I just imported data from 50 odd excels where the dates were **entered** in `DD/MM/YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY`, but most of the Excel files **stored** them as `MM/DD/YYYY` (Probably because the PCs were setup with `en-us` instead of `en-gb` or `en-in`).

Even more irritating was the fact that dates above `13/MM/YYYY` were in `DD/MM/YYYY` format still. So there was variations within the Excel files.

The most reliable solution I figured out was to manually set the Date column on each excel file to to be Plain Text -- then use this code to parse it:

```
if date_str_from_excel:
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_str_from_excel, '%d/%m/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        print("Unable to parse date")
```

Answer (score 1):

excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, if you want to get the dates in date format using python, just subtract 2 days from the days column, as shown below:

**Date = sheet.cell(1,0).value-2** //in python

at column 1 in my excel, i have my date and above command giving me date values minus 2 days, which is same as date present in my excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

This is a revised version from @hounded. My code handles both date and time, something like 43705.591795706

```
    import math
    import datetime


    def xldate_to_datetime(xldatetime): #something like 43705.6158241088

      tempDate = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 31)
      (days, portion) = math.modf(xldatetime)

      deltaDays = datetime.timedelta(days=days)
      #changing the variable name in the edit
      secs = int(24 * 60 * 60 * portion)
      detlaSeconds = datetime.timedelta(seconds=secs)
      TheTime = (tempDate + deltaDays + detlaSeconds )
      return TheTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


xldate_to_datetime(43705.6158241088)
# 2019-08-29 14:46:47
```

Comment: according to the official docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/troubleshoot/access/store-calculate-compare-datetime-data) the reference date should be __30th__ of December

Answer (score 0):

For quick and dirty:

```
year, month, day, hour, minute, second = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(excelDate, wb.datemode)
whatYouWant = str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of peoples post gave me the date and the time for excel conversion. I did return it as a string

```
def xldate_to_datetime(xldate):
  tempDate = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
  deltaDays = datetime.timedelta(days=int(xldate))
  secs = (int((xldate%1)*86400)-60)
  detlaSeconds = datetime.timedelta(seconds=secs)
  TheTime = (tempDate + deltaDays + detlaSeconds )
  return TheTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: your code does not look correct - for example, 43704 should be 8/27/2019. Your code returns 2019-08-28 23:59:00

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datetime column in excel file. Then below code will fix it. I went through a lot of answers on StackOverflow and nothing fixed it. I thought file is corrupted.

```
from datetime import datetime
jsts = 1468629431.0
datetime.fromtimestamp(jsts)
```

Answer (score -2):

When converting an excel file to CSV the date/time cell looks like this:

foo, 3/16/2016 10:38, bar,

To convert the datetime text value to datetime python object do this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_object = datetime.strptime('3/16/2016 10:38', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')    # excel format (CSV file)
```

print date_object  will return 2005-06-01 13:33:00

Comment: OP want answer for xlrd, as xlrd returns in float