# Python - Reading a spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

What I need to know is, can I get Python to read a spreadsheet (preferably Microsoft Excel), then parse the information and input it into an equation?

It's for a horse-racing program, where the information for several horses will be in one excel spreadsheet, in different rows or columns. I need to know if I can run a calculation for each of those horses separately and then calculate a score for the given horse.

Comment: Excel is not a database.

Comment: What is the equation? and do you have example data?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? You can't expect contributors to just do your work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459788/get-the-inputs-from-excel-and-use-those-inputs-in-python-script) - and probably many others...

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is:

1. Save the Excel file as a `csv` comma separated value file, which is a plain text format and much easier to work with.
2. Use Python's [built-in `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) to work with the data in csv format.

You can work with Excel files directly in Python (Excel 2003 format supported via the third party modules [xlwt, xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/)) but this is much harder than working with CSV.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenPyXL](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/) ("A Python library to read/write Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm files") has a very nice and Pythonic API.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xlrd` package. [It's on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), so you can just `easy_install xlrd`

Answer (score 0):

You can export the spreadsheet as a .csv and read it in as a text file, then process it. I have a niggling feeling there might even a CSV parsing python library.

AFAIK there isn't a .xls parser, although I might be wrong.

EDIT: I was wrong: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: The `csv` module is built into Python. And there's no Excel parser in vanilla Python, though there are third party modules. `xlrd` and `xlwt` are fairly mature but don't work on the Excel 2007 format.

Comment: Ah ok, we use CSV files to introduce first year UG's into python file I/O, so I've only ever done simplistic string parsing with them. That's good to know though!

Comment: The built-in `csv` module handles a lot of the edge cases that a naive parser doesn't. Commas inside quoted strings, oddities of the CSV format written by Excel, that kind of thing. It's OK to write your own CSV parser as a learning exercise, but production code should always use the `csv` module.

Comment: Why the historical downvote, 4 years after I made this post?!