# Library for manipulating Excel and Libreoffice Calc sheets in Ruby or Python

Tags: python, ruby, excel, libraries, libreoffice

I have two different spreadsheets that include grades of project groups of students and another three spreadsheets that include students' ID's with respect to sections.

I want to combine these two different sheets to give individual grades of students near their ID's. I intend to write a script instead of doing it manually. Thus, I'm looking for a good library to use with Ruby or Python. Is there any such library that might work for my purpose?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this question? I am willing to rewrite it, but for me it ask its question very clearly, so I need to know what would nned to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's been answered here [Python - Reading a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227200/python-reading-a-spreadsheet)

I think saving as .csv and using python's built in .csv support is the best option: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

Python libraries:
  * for ODS files you can try: http://simple-odspy.sourceforge.net/
  * for Excel files: http://scienceoss.com/read-excel-files-from-python/