# Converting date/time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have stock ticker data in the following format:

```
40289.65972
40289.66319
40289.66667
```

and Excel is able to *magically* convert them to:

```
4/22/14 3:50 PM
4/22/14 3:55 PM
4/22/14 4:00 PM
```

via "Format Cells"

How do I do the same conversion in `pandas`?

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python to convert your ``floats`` into instances of ``datetime.datetime`` which you can use in Pandas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stay within pandas (which is wicked fast), use `to_timedelta()`

```
import pandas as pd
# should get  7/7/1988 1:26:24 a.m. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214094)
pd.to_datetime('1899-12-30') + pd.to_timedelta(32331.06, 'D')
```

produces
`Timestamp('1988-07-07 01:26:24')`
If you have a dataframe full of excel-float-dates you can convert the whole thing:

```
df['BetterDT'] = pd.to_datetime('1899-12-30') + pd.to_timedelta(df.ExecDate, 'D')
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution mentioned in the link above works, so I will just repost the snippet here. Thanks!

```
import datetime

def minimalist_xldate_as_datetime(xldate, datemode):
    # datemode: 0 for 1900-based, 1 for 1904-based
    return (
        datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
        + datetime.timedelta(days=xldate + 1462 * datemode)
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel considers 1900 a leap year, so be careful with exactly what you want to translate: 
http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/the_intentional_date_bug/

Comment: The link is broken, can you elaborate?