# Reading date as a string not float from excel using python xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read a date in Excel format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python)

My date can be among any field in an excel file but when I read it using python xlrd its being read as a float. Is there a way to read all the excel cells as string?

I want to prepare a script to generate a file having all the values in excel file separated by a pipe but this date thing is creating problem.

Comment: can you post your current code and some sample data?

Comment: @Linuxios You definitely misunderstood. Excel stores dates as floats. For example, 11-1-88 is stored as 32448.0.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Excel stores dates as floats. If you want to convert them `xlrd` has a function to help you with this: [xldate_as_tuple](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function)

An exmple:

```
import datetime, xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("myfile.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
a1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
a1_as_datetime = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode))
print 'datetime: %s' % a1_as_datetime
```

Comment: @dedoco....is there any way to edit date mode so that in output we have date in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @KundanKumar `datetime`has a variety of output options, to my knowledge (I'm not very familiar with `datetime`) the closes format to what you want is the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD) which you get by: `a1_as_datetime.date().isoformat()`

Comment: @KundanKumar the point is, excel stores only the float, so if you want to print the date in a readable format, I'm afraid you will have to convert it first. There is no way around this. ...if you are happy with my answer, please consider to mark it as the right answer ;).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41155121/786326

Comment: Late to the party, but for anyone dropping by: add .strftime("%m/%d/%Y") behind the datetime() method for the mm/dd/yyyy format @KundanKumar is asking for