# Python xlrd read DateTime as serial number

Tags: python, excel, datetime, xlrd

I have an excel which is a DateTime format. But when I read the sheet it reads as serial number.

For example, in the sheet it's `08/03/2015` but xlrd reads as `42219`.

The code is pretty simple

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=excel_contents)
the_sheet = workbook.sheet_names()[0]
number_of_rows = the_sheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = 0
data = []

while curr_row < number_of_rows:
    curr_row += 1
    air_date = the_sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 1)
    air_time = the_sheet.cell_value(curr_row, 2)
    schedule_time = '{}:{}'.format(air_date, air_time)
    unaware = datetime.strptime(schedule_time, '%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p')
```

The `air_date` which I use to translate to `datetime` in Python bombs out because the format is different.

This is the example excel.

[image]

And here's the error I got

> builtins.ValueError ValueError: time data '42219.0:06:00 AM' does not
>   match format '%m/%d/%Y:%I:%M %p'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use `xldate_as_tuple` to convert the excel format into a python format ( See [documentation](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate%5Fas%5Ftuple-function) and [this already existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962837/reading-date-as-a-string-not-float-from-excel-using-python-xlrd) where you will find the format to convert the date to python.

> **xldate_as_tuple :**
>
> Convert an Excel number (presumed to represent a date, a datetime or a time) into a tuple suitable for feeding to datetime or mx.DateTime constructors.