# why pandas in python does not return all the rows from excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

this is my code and my excel sheet has 1000 rows and 22 columns of data.
i want to convert excel to text file. but when i run this, i only get first and line 5 rows and columns of data? how to solve this issue

```py
import pandas as pd
xlsFile = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:/Users/vivek/OneDrive/Desktop/College Project/modules/spreadSheetManipulation/sample.xlsx')
totalPages= xlsFile.sheet_names
with open(r'C:/Users/vivek/OneDrive/Desktop/College Project/modules/spreadSheetManipulation/output.txt','w') as textFile:
    for page in totalPages:
        dataFrame = xlsFile.parse(page)
        textFile.write("\nSheet name is:"+page+"\n")
        textFile.write(str(dataFrame))
        textFile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Why not just use `pd.read_excel()`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```py
import pandas as pd

with open(r'C:/Users/vivek/OneDrive/Desktop/College Project/modules/spreadSheetManipulation/sample.xlsx', 'w') as file:
    pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/vivek/OneDrive/Desktop/College Project/modules/spreadSheetManipulation/output.txt').to_string(file, index=False)
```

code pulled from:
[Convert .xlsx to .txt with python? or format .txt file to fix columns indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654011/convert-xlsx-to-txt-with-python-or-format-txt-file-to-fix-columns-indentatio)