# convert numerical representation of date (excel format) to python date and time, then split them into two seperate dataframe columns in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas

I'm importing some data in a spreadsheet. It's in a dataframe, but the date is in a numerical representation or format

```
41516.43
```

First, I want to convert it to a date and time object

```
date_val = 30/08/2013  10:13:26 AM
```

Then I would like to split the date_val into date and time separately, and place them in seperate columns in my dataframe (df)

```
| **original date** | **date**     | **time** | 
41516.43              30/08/2013      10:13:26 AM
```

Comment: what is this numerical format?

Comment: The date (as a short date) in excel, but then I removed all formatting. from the whole spreadsheet, making it much easier to read. So in short an excel date format?

Comment: This page says DATE time Serial Number is the format.. no more detail than that. http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/available-number-formats-HA102749055.aspx

Comment: How are you getting the csv, have you tried using to_excel?

Comment: @AndyHayden
I did use the To Excel > And I get >> 41516.43. I chose not to parse dates on import because I usually import the data as is, spend time looking at it to see what I can do. I don't usually have the luxury of knowing how many columns I will have and the format's of those columns.

Answer (score 6):

Piecing together from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([41516.43])

In [12]: from xlrd.xldate import xldate_as_tuple

In [13]: from datetime import datetime

In [14]: s.apply(lambda x: datetime(*xldate_as_tuple(x, 0)))
Out[14]:
0   2013-08-30 10:19:12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note: presumably slight difference is due to rounding of the float you gave.

and the ["bare-knuckle no-seat-belts use-at-own-risk"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112664/1240268) version:

```
In [21]: pd.Timestamp('1899-12-30') + (pd.offsets.Day(1).nanos * s).astype(np.timedelta64)
Out[21]:
0   2013-08-30 10:19:12
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*I think it's generally preferable to do parse dates while using [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html).*

Comment: Thanks for that. Would you mind trying to explain what is LAMDA, and how it works. I keep seeing it around, but have no idea what it's doing. Is it essentially making 3 lines of code into 1? Can you still write your lamda statement another way without lamda?

Comment: Also @ Andy Hayden, why do you have to convert the floating point number to a series first?\

Comment: @yoshiserry a column in a DataFrame is a Series. Lambda if an inline way of making a function.

Comment: could you do it with a normal function, and not lamda, I.e. are there ways of doing it without using lamda?

Comment: @yoshiserry yes, a lambda is the same as a function, it's just inline. So you can do `def f(x): return datetime(*xldate_as_tuple(x, 0))`.