# How to covert XLDate type in excel to text type in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

How can I convert  XLDate type in excel to text type in python.
I am using xlrd to read excel sheet. But ,for example ,a cell contains 14:00 will be read as
0.5833333333333334 by xlrd.

**Edit1**

I read cell using:

```
r=sheet1.cell(2,4).value
```

**Edit2**

Cell format in excel is hh:mm.

Comment: At least related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python

Comment: `sheet1.cell(2,4).Text`?

Comment: No, It doesn't work because 'Cell' object has no attribute 'text'.