# Dynamics CRM 2011 Timestamp into Python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, timestamp, dynamics-crm-2011

I am exporting data from Dynamics CRM 2011 into an Excel File. The entries have timestamps. In CRM they look like normal dates, but when I export them into Excel the timestamps look similar to this:

41855.4043865741

41831.6309259259

In Excel I can right-click on the cell with the timestamp and do Cell Formatting > Numbers > Date and convert this to a human readable string.

e.g. 
04.08.2014  09:42:19

11.07.2014  15:08:32

The problem is, after I save the Excel with the human readable Datetime format and read the Excel with the xlrd Module (Python 2.7) I still get the strange format and not the translated one.

So I tried using datetime Module to dranslate the date but when doing so I get the wrong date.

```
import datetime
str_dt = float(41831.6309259259)
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(str_dt).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

My result is: 1970-01-01 12:37:11
Of course it is not Unixtimestamp but I have no idea what timestamp it actually is and how I can convert it with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you see are the actual number of days since the 1st of January 1900. This is the format used by CRM and Excel.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109523/439761), you can use [`xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/df3910f3e32b1bc541aa6f34f00ad0ef2789e798/xlrd/xldate.py#L60) to:

> Convert an Excel date/time number into a datetime.datetime object.
>
> `@param xldate` The Excel number
>   `@param datemode` 0: 1900-based, 1:
>   1904-based.
>
> `@return` a `datetime.datetime()` object.

In your case the datemode would be 0.