# Reading seconds from excel sheet using python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

i have the one cell with 00:00:44 seconds in excel i want it to print as it is 
but i am getting like float number 
this is what i printed on dictionary 'Avg. Visitor Response Time': 0.0005092592592592592,
these are time responses in my excel sheet  every time i read , i am getting only floating numbers
0:00:36
0:00:36
0:00:33
0:00:32
0:00:36
0:00:39
0:00:44
0:00:40
0:00:46
0:00:42
0:00:43
0:00:43
0:00:41
0:00:42

can you please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The answers to the question @pete23 mentions are good.

If you're dealing with time values (i.e., float values less than 1.0), just multiply by 86400 to get the number of seconds.

Comment: what i am done is L=0.00050929272*86400)    m,s=divmod(L,60) h,m=divmod(m,60) print("%2d:%2d:%2d"%(h,m,s) , got the output  as format of input 00:00:43 but not exact of 00:00:44 finally rounded  the value

Comment: If you round L to 13 digits (or fewer), you'll get 00:00:44 - personally I'd probably round to 4 digits at the most (and I'd consider rounding to 0 or 1 digit).