# How to read the text in excel cell and replace with someother value in json output using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, xlrd

My python code reads the excel sheet and converts it into a json file output. I have a column in the excel sheet, where the values are either "Planned" or "Unplanned".

1)In the json output, I want the Planned to be replaced with "1" and Unplanned to be replaced with "2" without changing anything in the excel file. 
2)In the output I dont want "data" to appear. 
3)In the excel, my Start time column value is like this "2018-11-16  08:00:00". I want the output to be "2018-11-16T08:00:00Z". Currently i am getting some garbage value.
Below is my code.

```
import xlrd, json, time, pytz, requests
from os import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict

def json_from_excel():
    excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
    jsonfile = open('ExceltoJSON.json', 'w')
    data = []
    datestr = str(datetime.now().date())
    loaddata = OrderedDict()

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('OMS-GX Data Extraction')
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for j in range(0, 6):
    for i in range(1, 40):
        temp = {}
        temp["requestedStart"] = (sheet.cell_value(i,0))      #Start Time
        temp["requestedComplete"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 1))  #End Time
        temp["location"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 3))           #Station
        temp["equipment"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 4))          #Device Name
        temp["switchOrderTypeID"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 5))  #Outage Type
        data.append(temp)
        loaddata['data'] = data



    json.dump(loaddata, jsonfile, indent=3, sort_keys=False)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
    return loaddata



 if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = json_from_excel()
```

Below is my sample output:

```
 {
   "data": [
      {
         "requestedStart": testtime,
         "requestedComplete": testtime,
         "location": "testlocation",
         "equipment": "testequipment",
         "switchOrderTypeID": "Planned"
      },
      {
         "requestedStart": testtime,
         "requestedComplete": testtime,
         "location": "testlocation",
         "equipment": "testequipment",
         "switchOrderTypeID": "Unplanned"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the 1st question:
You may use conditional assignment.

`temp["switchOrderTypeID"] = (1 if sheet.cell_value(i, 5) == "Planned" else 0)`

Answer to the 2nd question:
Use `loaddata = data` which will be an array of the jsons without `data` as json key.

Answer to 3rd question:

`from dateutil.parser import parse
t = "2018-11-16 08:00:00"
parse(t).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Could you help for the second one?

Comment: Try `loaddata = data`. It will be an array of json if that works. Because currently, `data` is a json key which holds your rest of the data. Or let me know what is the expected output format.

Comment: I have added a third question. Would you please help with that too?

Comment: For the answer to the 3rd question, Could you please let me know how to change in the line here,
 temp["requestedStart"] = (sheet.cell_value(i,0))

Comment: replace t with your cell value. `temp["requestedStart"] =  parse(sheet.cell_value(i,0)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Comment: This is the error for the above changes, TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not float

Comment: could you tell me what is the value of sheet.cell_value(i,0) and type of the same?

Comment: In excel sheet, the value is "2018-11-16 08:00:00" . But in json output, for sheet.cell_value(1, 0) is 43420.333336

Comment: If sheet.cell_value(i,0) is string then it has to be parsed and then use strftime `parse(t).strftime("format")`. Othewise if it is a datetime object already, directly use strftime `t.strftime("format").

Comment: Refer this: You will have to change the way of fetching date from excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python